# pandas: convert a list in a column into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

dataframe df has a column

```
id  data_words
1   [salt,major,lab,water]
2   [lab,plays,critical,salt]
3   [water,success,major]
```

I want to make one-hot-code of the column

```
id  critical        lab         major    plays     salt    success   water 
1   0               1           1        0         1       0         1
2   1               1           0        1         1       0         0
3   0               0           1        1         0       1         0
```

What I tried:

**Attempt 1:**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('data_words')),
                          columns=mlb.classes_,
                          index=df.index))

Error: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['class'], dtype='object')
```

**Attempt 2:**

I converted the list into simple comma separated string with the following code

```
df['data_words_Joined'] = df.data_words.apply(','.join)
```

it makes the dataframe as following

```
id  data_words
1   salt,major,lab,water
2   lab,plays,critical,salt
3   water,success,major
```

Then I tried

```
pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['data_words_Joined'])],axis=1)
```

But It makes all the words into one column name instead of separate words as separate columns

```
id  salt,major,lab,water    lab,plays,critical,salt    water,success,major
1   1                       0                          0
2   0                       1                          0  
3   0                       0                          1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach could be to use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with your `apply` function:

```
new_df = df.data_words.apply(','.join).str.get_dummies(sep=',')
print(new_df)
```

**Output**:

```
    critical  lab  major  plays  salt  success  water
0         0    1      1      0     1        0      1
1         1    1      0      1     1        0      0
2         0    0      1      0     0        1      1
```

**Tested with `pandas` version `1.1.2` and borrowed input data from [Celius Stingher's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11897007/celius-stingher) Answer**.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `explode` followed by `pivot_table`

```
df_e = df.explode('data_words')
print(df_e.pivot_table(index=df_e['id'],columns=df_e['data_words'],values='id',aggfunc='count',fill_value=0))
```

Returning the following output:

```
data_words  critical  lab  major  plays  salt  success  water
id                                                           
1                  0    1      1      0     1        0      1
2                  1    1      0      1     1        0      0
3                  0    0      1      0     0        1      1
```

Edit: Adding data for replication purposes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
      'data_words':[['salt','major','lab','water'],['lab','plays','critical','salt'],['water','success','major']]})
```

Which looks like:

```
   id                    data_words
0   1     [salt, major, lab, water]
1   2  [lab, plays, critical, salt]
2   3       [water, success, major]
```

Comment: I don't get the same output as you (when running your command)
- are you able to add the data to your answer as well so I can make sure `df` is the same in both cases please

Comment: thanks, if reading with `pd.read_clipboard()` (where the OP output from the top of the question post is on the clipboard) then `.explode` doesn't work, but does if constructing from scratch as you have in your post. Thanks for updating.

Comment: Yeah of course, I suppose they are lists and not strings looking as lists. But if they were strings you could use ast.literal_eval() to match the output.

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @Khaned what pandas and python version are you using? You can replicate the exact same code in google colab where there's no compatibility issues.